# Raining inside workshop

Tags: water, roof, rain

The place where I do my diy stuff keeps getting wet because whenever it rains the water gets inside through the roof, the roof looks *generally* like this stock photo of a tile roof (this is not my roof):

[image: 1]

I have put this isolating sheets: [image: test]
<sub>(source: [warmup.pt](http://www.warmup.pt/assets/pt-piso-radiante/_resampled/PaddedImage570316FFFFFF-placas-isolamento-sem-revestimento.jpg))</sub>

On the inside and siliconed them to the concrete (on some of them applied isolating foam spray to the borders) but water still gets in through one of the borders (siliconed), what do I do to stop this, already got an angle grinder broken because of the rain (left it on the table and it got soaked)?

Photos of the roof setup:
[image]

[image]

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/89he486zegulxit/15731288_1410928465608812_774723163_n.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn6x1j4uaoexp7g/14970833_1352211198147206_137584259_o.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rdndqnwdtn2sv6/14513567_1313594228675570_596033170_o.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your roof has failed. Unfortunately, if that's the case, there isn't anything that can be done inside the structure. The water will always have to go somewhere. Short of building a second ceiling inside, you're stuck.

I'd say call in a roofer to take a look, they'll know the warning signs and can tell you if it's a repair or a replacement kind of job. Might be a couple tiles have broken, or a problem with the roofing underlay (tar paper or similar).

You may be in luck though, that plastic (I'm guessing) roofing tile may be removable/patchable without being destroyed, which would make the roofer's job much easier.

There is a very small chance that this is internal condensations collecting on the new panels, or just above them. Did it do this before you installed the panels?

Comment: No tiles are broken from what I can see.  The roofing tiles are ceramic I believe. Yeah it did this before I installed the panels that is the whole reason I installed them, to try and stop water from getting in, I went to material/hardware shop here in town and they recommended me doing this (they said it could be the wind blowing water in since the roof makes an angle)

Comment: "problem with the roofing underlay (tar paper or similar)." There is no roof underlay, that is probably the problem, they just added the tiles when they built this "shed" in the house's garden. Check this image I sent before: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rdndqnwdtn2sv6/14513567_1313594228675570_596033170_o.jpg?dl=0 Here you can see the tiles from the inside (this is before completing the isolating panel setup)

Comment: I think the hardware store led you wrong. The water has already entered the space before it hits your foam panels. Its not going to go back up into the concrete. The roof should have a layer of tar paper or some other water-resistant underlay beneath the tiles specifically to deal with water blowing in underneath them.

Comment: Do you know where I can buy tar paper? Hardware shop? (Is it expensive?) Do I have to take out all of the tiles to put it?

Comment: You would have to redo the roof yes. You should be able to find felt underlay (apparently the proper name) at the home center if in the US. Maybe at the local hardware store. A standard #30 (pronounced 30 pound). Its not too bad, about $10 / 100sqft. So for a smaller roof it won't break the bank. There's a lot of labor involved though, if you do it yourself do the research first.

Comment: Thank you, I will see what I can do. Probably will have to stand the rain for the winter and it will be a summer project